# Why should I install Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 instead of Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome-shell desktop installed?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, xfce, desktop-environments, lts

What would be the advantages of that? At Ubuntu GNOME site it says "*Ubuntu GNOME is a mostly pure GNOME desktop experience built from the Ubuntu repositories*", but I'm not sure what that means exactly.

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-shell installed. I am willing to upgrade to 14.04. Ubuntu LTS has 5 years support while Ubuntu GNOME has 3 years. That's what makes me think it would be better to install Ubuntu 14.04.

Actually, this question could be extended to any flavor of Ubuntu. Is there any difference between installing, let's say, Xubutu with the gnome-shell desktop and installing Ubuntu GNOME with xfce-desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter anyways since the gnome-shell specific packages are the ones that are getting only 3 years of support. The same can be said with any deskop you install, just because you install Ubuntu and install for example XFCE instead of Xubuntu doesn't magically means you will get 5 years of support for the XFCE specific packages.

This doesn't incluide of course Ubuntu core packages like the kernel for wich you will get Security Updates for 5 years in any desktop you use.